# Sorting least likely matches into groups - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

This is the table:

```
            name | id | 
            --------------------
            jim  | 267
            jill | 267
            larry| 268
            tim  | 269 
            riley| 267
            joe  | 301
            pete | 301
            gil  | 110
            shay : 701
            bill | 301
```

The desired result is separate into 5 categories, different numbers should be scattered across the categories while keeping same numbers together:

```
            cat 1    | cat 2    | cat 3  | cat 4   | cat 5
            ------------------------------------------------
            jim 267  |Larry 268 |joe 301 |gil 110  |shay 701
            jill 267 |tim 269   |pete 301|         |
            riley 267|          |bill 301|         |
```

So essentially I want to grouping like while separating different id's as much as possible.

Comment: And what did you tried?

Comment: This should help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns

Answer (score 0):

It looks you want grouping name and id wise. If so then it should be simple just make sure while grouping reverse the order

```
Select name,id from table group by id,name
```

Comment: yes, thats on the right track but results needs to be counted and ordered by most to least matches, this sorts but doesnt arrange.

Comment: Do you wish to arrange horizontally ?

Comment: yes, the ultimate goal is to arrange these in most matches to least matches. so most matches in one column to least in last column. I havbe had some success in test with count( * ) and having, even a php loop stepping through, but still a bit confused on how to achieve this